JMeter run http requests consecutively in a ThreadGroup without loop logic
In JMeter, I have 2 Http Requests in a thread group, A and B
If I set Number of threads (users) to 3 in the thread group, they run in the following manner
AAABBB instead of the desired ABABAB
Why I need it AB, because A produces a unique connection ID I need to store in a variable and use in B. Now, all B requests uses the ID of the last A request.
Before anyone suggests it, I know setting users to 1 and loop to 3 will get the job done but in my specific use-case, it is causing errors.
To sum it briefly, I am using Azure signalR. When I am using only 1 user, Azure is only reserving 1 connection. As the loop progress, it closes the i-1 connection and opens it again at i.
So practically, at the end of the test, only 1 connection is open instead of 3.
I am unable to perform a stress test on Azure when there is only ever 1 connection opening and closing in each iteration.
So, how can I run the 2 http requests consecutively while keeping loop 1 and users 3?

Each thread (virtual user) is running requests consecutively, you can check yourself if you add the following functions to your Samplers labels:

${__threadNum} - to see the number of current thread (virtual user)
${__groovy(vars.getIteration(),)} - to see the number of current iteration

you will see that:

1st user runs request A followed by request B
2nd user runs request A followed by request B

If you're looking into a listener like View Results Tree and seeing another order - this is due to concurrency and it's totally expected
